# How to keep two folders automatically synchronized?

Tags: bash, synchronization

I would like to have a synchronized copy of one folder with all its subtree.

It should work automatically in this way: whenever I create, modify, or delete stuff from the original folder those changes should be automatically applied to the sync-folder.

Which is the best approach to this task?

BTW: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04

Final goal is to have a separated real-time backup copy, without the use of symlinks or mount.
I used Ubuntu One to synchronize data between my computers, and after a while something went wrong and all my data was lost during a synchronization.

So I thought to add a step further to keep a backup copy of my data:

- I keep my data stored on a "folder A"
- I need the answer of my current question to create a one-way sync of "folder A" to "folder B" (`cron` a script with `rsync`? could be?). I need it to be one-way only from A to B any changes to B must not be applied to A.
- The I simply keep synchronized "folder B" with Ubuntu One

  In this manner any change in A will be appled to B, which will be detected from U1 and synchronized to the cloud. If anything goes wrong and U1 delete my data on B, I always have them on A.

Inspired by lanzz's comments, another idea could be to run rsync at startup to backup the content of a folder under Ubuntu One, and start Ubuntu One only after rsync is completed.

What do you think about that?
How to know when rsync ends?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do the folders truly need to be separate, can't you symlink one name to the other, or [bind-mount](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+mount+bind) the directory to the secondary location? Also, take a look at [these search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=sync+inotify).

Comment: I'd advise _against_ actual live synchronization (i.e. watching continuously for file changes in the source directory) in favor of periodic `rsync` via cron.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You can use `inotifywait` (with the `modify,create,delete,move` flags enabled) and `rsync`.

```
while inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete,move /directory; do
    rsync -avz /directory /target
done
```

If you don't have `inotifywait` on your system, run `sudo apt-get install inotify-tools`

Comment: You might wanna consider to add `-e ssh user@remote:/target` to `rsync` if you want to use SSH as transport to access your remote machine.

Comment: Thanks @Falcon, I usually use `rsync -avz --delete --exclude-from=.rsyncignore /directory user@server:path`. However I wanted to write a simple answer.

Comment: to clarify: is this a one-time-run thing, or would you add this to a bashrc or something?

Comment: You can consider the whole while loop as a process that synchronizes when needed. I usually add it to the Makefile of the project I'm working on. This way I can choose the server and the directory I want it to be saved. One of my use cases is when I program deep learning algorithms in my laptop and I synchronize it to perform the heavy process in a dedicated computer with better CPU and a GPU. I also exclude files that I don't need, such as the `.git` folder.

Comment: This doesn't handle file renames, use `modify,create,delete,move`

Comment: You're completely correct, thanks for the comment @urusha , I updated the answer ;)

Comment: Just 2 tips I found helpful when trying this:

1. If inotifywait is not installed, you need to `apt-get install inotify-tools` (or `dnf`, `yum`, `pacman` ... etc).

2. To run this on startup, add it to `/etc/rc.local` before the exit line.

Comment: This is one-way. It's like a backup.

Comment: 2 more "perfectionist" corrections to the example script: 1) if we don't use `rsync --delete`, there is no need to listen for the `delete` event, 2) `inotifywait`, at least in its current version, listens to all events _by default_.

Answer (score 34):

You need something like this:
https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd
It is a tool which combines rsync and inotify - the former is a tool that mirrors, with the correct options set, a directory to the last bit. The latter tells the kernel to notify a program of changes to a directory ot file. 
It says:

> It aggregates and combines events for a few seconds and then spawns one (or more) process(es) to synchronize the changes.

But - according to Digital Ocean at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-mirror-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps-with-lsyncd - it ought to be in the Ubuntu repository!

I have similar requirements, and this tool, which I have yet to try, seems suitable for the task.

Comment: lsyncd at first seemed like a silver bullet, but it has [lots of open issues](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/issues) and apparently the macOS implementation is "old and outdated." I couldn't get it to work on 10.12.

Comment: @apaidnerd To be fair, it's 90 issues open vs 420 closed. Though, only 10/40 issues were closed in the last year.

Answer (score 10):

Just simple modification of @silgon answer:

```
while true; do 
  inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete /directory
  rsync -avz /directory /target
done
```

(@silgon version sometimes crashes on Ubuntu 16 if you run it in cron)

Comment: Why would you run it in cron?

Comment: @saygley For a specific task, after Ubuntu rebooting the sync process should be run automatically

Comment: I see.. Nevertheless, since this normally should be started once and be running as long as the server is up; I would consider something inlined within rc.local instead.

Comment: I inclued `sleep 15m` soyou can see logged changes

Answer (score 7):

Using the cross-platform [`fswatch`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) and `rsync`:

```
fswatch -o /src | xargs -n1 -I{} rsync -a /src /dest
```

Comment: beautiful!! combing back here for the 2nd time!

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of [fschange](http://stefan.buettcher.org/cs/fschange/). It’s a Linux filesystem change notification.  The source code is downloadable from the above link, you can compile it yourself. `fschange` can be used to keep track of file changes by reading data from a proc file (/proc/fschange). When data is written to a file, fschange reports the exact interval that has been modified instead of just saying that the file has been changed. 
If you are looking for the more advanced solution, I would suggest checking [Resilio Connect](https://www.resilio.com/connect). 
It is cross-platform, provides extended options for use and monitoring. Since it’s BitTorrent-based, it is faster than any other existing sync tool. It was written on their behalf.

Answer (score 1):

I use this free program to synchronize local files and directories: https://github.com/Fitus/Zaloha.sh. The repository contains a simple demo as well.

The good point: It is a bash shell script (one file only). Not a black box like other programs. Documentation is there as well. Also, with some technical talents, you can "bend" and "integrate" it to create the final solution you like.